# How can i fix this error on SSL certificate

Tags: python, ssl-certificate

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt

Hello i'am trying to install some python package but i still get this error can someone help me with this?

Comment: I'd guess you have an environment variable set to have Pip look at PostgreSQL CA certificates for SSL. You'll need to figure out if that's the case, and reconfigure that accordingly.

Comment: Install "some python package"? Don't you think that being a bit more specific would help to get an answer?

Comment: I originally install PostgreSQL but my colleague told me it was no use so i uninstall it. After that I try to install seaborn for visualisation that's i receive an error message. i try other packages but still the same issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AKX ' s answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered with the same problem so here is how I solved it:

I just reinstalled whole PostgreSQL, especially PostgreSQL bundle, I think we accidentally deleted this and encountered with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error, you likely need to to **check your Environment variables under system variables** if on a windows PC.
**Deleting this variable should solve your issue**. It likely came in during a Postgres installation which tells your system to only trust installations from hosts allowed by that certificate. If that certificate does not exist or does not allow pypi.org, you would encounter this error for every `pip install`  command.

See below;

[image: image showing environment variable to be removed]